# If a language is m-reducible to a regular language, does it mean that this language is also necessarily a regular language?

Tags: complexity-theory, formal-languages, reductions

I've been going back and forth with this for a dew days, can't quite be sure.

When I look at the pumping lemma method, I think a context-free language could possibly be reduced to a regular language.

Comment: The answer depends on the definition of *m-reducible*. This is not quite a standard notion, so you'll have to fill us in.

Comment: Mapping-reducible. As in there is a computable function 'f' so that for every word 'w' in a given language 'A',  f(w) belongs in language 'B', if A is m-reducible to B.

Comment: By the way, welcome to the site!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your question is no. There's a general result you can use in this case:

**Theorem**. If $A$ and $B$ are any decidable languages and $B\ne\varnothing$ and $B\ne\Sigma^*$, then $A\le_\text{M} B$.

This says that any nontrivial decidable languages are mapping reducible to each other. In other words, mapping reducibility tells you nothing about decidable languages.

Here's an example. Let $L=\{0^n1^n\mid n\ge 0\}$. This is a well-known non-regular language. Now let $R$ be, say the regular language $\{0\}$. Then $L\le_\text{M} R$ by the mapping $f:\{0, 1\}^*\rightarrow\{0, 1\}^*$ defined by
$$
f(s) = \begin{cases}
0\quad\text{if $s=0^n1^n$ for some $n\ge 0$}\\
1\quad\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
It's obvious that $f$ is Turing-computable and that $s\in \{0^n1^n\} \Longleftrightarrow f(s)\in R$, which is exactly what you need to show that this non-regular language is mapping reducible to this regular language.

Comment: I'm puzzled. It's plain, as you explain it, that $L\le_\text{M} R$, but how can the converse ($R\le_\text{M} L$) be true? How can we reduce $R$ to $L$? Wouldn't this violate the definition of a function?

Comment: @PartialOrder the other direction is even easier: $f(s)=\begin{cases}\epsilon&\text{if }s=0\\0&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$.

Comment: @kai Ah! Each element in R maps to *an* element in L. I was thinking (mistakenly) that we needed an onto function for each element in L. Thanks for clarifying.